# Blender Precise Pulling

Tags: 3d, 3d-modeling, blender

Hello dear forum friends.

So I've been working for with blender and I saw people using numbers to specify how much a part of the model will go out and in.

eg. I want to pull a part of the model from one side by 5 in the x axis and from the other side 5 on the x axis and it must be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can press **"g"** to start moving a selection and then lock it to an axis by pressing **"x"**, **"y"** or **"z"**. After this you can enter a numeric value to move the selection.

E.g.

Select a cube then press **"g"**, **"z"**, **2** and **enter**. It will move the cube 2 units in the z axis. With a negative value it will move the selection in the opposite  direction.

You can use this tip with rotation and scale too.